# In the Task Manager in Windows 10, how is exiting a task on the Details tab different from exiting a task on the Process tab?

Tags: windows, windows-10, driver, taskmanager

I am testing ObRegisterCallbacks in the Windows driver sample code, to protect the process.

see: [registered callbacks for process protection](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/obcallback)

In the details section my exe file is protected from the end task. 
However, if you do an end task in the Process tab, it will not be protected.

I want to know how the end task works in the processes tab.

Thank you for reading this article.

Comment: Ending a task sends `WM_CLOSE` to its top-level windows, and IIRC it falls back on `TerminateProcess` after waiting for a second. taskkill.exe includes both top-level and message-only windows, and it only terminates if we use the `/F` option to forcefully kill a task.

Comment: I fixed your link syntax and made it a bit more understandable.